# Using query yes/no field for checkbox record source?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, checkbox

First of all, you start with a form named LoginF. Once you choose your login ID, and password; and log in it takes data from the table LoginIntoT for the login ID you chose, and creates a query with said data using this code:

```
   On Error Resume Next
           DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, "IsAdminQ"
   On Error GoTo Err_LoginBtn_Click

     Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
       Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("IsAdminQ", _
                                           "SELECT IsAdmin " & _
                                           "FROM LoginInfoT " & _
                                           "WHERE EmployeeID = " & LoginCmBx.Value)


    Exit_LoginBtn_Click:
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "LoginF", acSaveNo
            DoCmd.OpenForm "MenuF"
       Exit Sub
    Err_LoginBtn_Click:
       MsgBox Err.Description
       Resume Exit_LoginBtn_Click
```

From there in that query after you log in is only 1 column and 1 row; meaning one piece of data. This data is a yes/no field which is either Yes or No depending on who you logged in as.

On the form it opens after you click the login button it has a logout button. The logout button brings you to the previous login form, and deletes the query (IsAdminQ).

What I am trying to do is attach a yes/no button on a form to take that data, and output if it's yes or no on the query.

I've tried putting this in it's control source:

=[IsAdminQ].[IsAdmin]

Though what that does is output it as a filled in square instead of a checkmark or empty. I have triple state set as no.

How would I attach the checkbox to the query so if the data says yes, then it's a check mark and if it says no it is an empty box?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: I am trying to attach a checkbox to a query. Though when I type that information into the checkbox's record source, it outputs the 3rd option (both yes and no) when it should be yes.

Comment: IF you are afraid of exposing your code, please put some other examples to illustrate your problem. Put some sample data, expected output and what you have tried already so that we could work a way out.

Comment: edited with more information, is that better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you.

"On the form it opens after you click the login button it has a logout button", we call it frmLogout. You shall do this:

#### Solution I:

```
frmLogout.RecordSource = "IsAdminQ"
```

Then for your checkbox named MyCheckbox, we set it this:

```
Me.MyCheckbox.ControlSource = "IsAdmin"
```

You cannot use this:

```
Me.MyCheckbox.ControlSource = "[IsAdminQ].[IsAdmin]"  ' <= here it's impossible.
```

#### Solution II:

On the form frmLogout without setting IsAdminQ as .RecordSource,

In a Public Module, insert this:

```
Function GetLoginStateIsAdmin()
'
  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordSet("IsAdminQ")

  GetLoginStateIsAdmin = Nz(rst(0), False)

  Set rst = Nothing
'
End Function
```

Then in the private module of any form, as frmLogout:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
'
  Me.MyCheckbox.Value = GetLoginStateIsAdmin()
'
End Sub
```

Set it in addition in design mode:

```
Me.MyCheckbox.TripleState = false
```

And check also if the query IsAdminQ has been successfully created in the login step. And open it in Access Navigation Pane by double-clicking on it. And see the value of the query.

Comment: This helps a lot and I'll end up using this. Though, is there a way to work around the need of setting the form's record source? I am going to set up this checkbox on every form in my database to check if the user is an admin; so if they are they can right click, and if they aren't they can't right click. Though some of my forms already have a record source set. Is it possible to set two record sources, or just simply bypass the need of using a form record source in this?

Comment: You should execute the query to get the value, then set Me.MyCheckbox.value = [Value of Checkbox gotten by VBA]

Comment: Weirdly enough when I apply that code to the form then log in; it spits out this error: Run-time error '2448': You can't assign a value to this object.

Comment: You must clean this Me.MyCheckbox.ControlSource = "" in design mode first before setting value for it.

Comment: Okay, now it starts up with no errors. Though the checkbox is the 3rd state on state up, and I can modify the checkbox.

Comment: Well, it still sets it self as the 3rd state when it should set it self as a check.

Comment: MsgBox GetLoginStateIsAdmin() ? must be 0 or 1, -1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40638/discussion-between-d347hxd-and-jacouh)